# Flagging issues in android

Tags: android, flags

I'm trying to get my Notification to not cancel when the user presses "Clear All" So far I have the intent working properly on everything except this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT);
    intent.addFlags(Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0, intent, 0);
```

The question I have at this point is: Are my flags correct?

Comment: So, you get an Ongoing notification, but it is clearable?

Comment: I dont want it to be clearable, And for some reason every time I try to run it, it wont come up as Ongoing just a normal notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your flags look pretty much correct, although I don't know if you even need the `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`. I currently have an app which creates an ongoing (non-cancellable) notification - I only use the `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT` and it works fine for me. I pretty much just copied it from a tutorial and then added the ongoing event flag. 
Here's some sample code:

```
String text = "notification";
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text,
        System.currentTimeMillis());

//launch the activity if the user selects this notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent().setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.example/com.example.MyActivity")), 0);

// set the label and text...
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_label),
               text, contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

// Send the notification.
// We use a string id because it is a unique number.  We use it later to cancel.
NotificationManager mNM;
mNM.notify(R.string.notification_label, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks man, this helped out a whole lot. I did not have it set to "notification.flags" Before! What a difference that can make!